# Disabling scrollbar in Ultrawingrd control

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

How do I hide/disable horizontal scrollbar in an Infragistics Ultrawingrd control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.None;`

[see this article](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout~Scrollbars.html)

Comment: Great answer, but your link is broken.